# how to handle procedure wrong input parameters error using exception block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exception

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_product_listing
(
     @product varchar(30),
     @month   datetime,
     @year    datetime
)
AS
  SELECT
     'product_name' = products.name,
     products.unit_price,
     products.quantity_in_stock,
     'supplier_name' = suppliers.name
  FROM
     suppliers
  INNER JOIN
     products ON suppliers.supplier_id = products.supplier_id    
  INNER JOIN
     order_details ON products.product_id = order_details.product_id
  INNER JOIN
     orders ON order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
  WHERE
     products.name = @product 
     AND MONTH ('orders.order_date') = @month 
     AND YEAR ('orders.order_date') = @year;
GO
```

When some try to execute the procedure with wrong input, instead of getting this error message catch in exception block

```
    Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 0
    Error converting data type varchar to datetime.
```

Comment: Could you show the `order_date` column type of the `orders` table?

Comment: It is impossible to validate the input pram of an SP inside the same sp !
For your information Both `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` have return value integer. 

How could you bind the values `datetime` with `int` ?

Answer (score 1):

> *From my comments : It is impossible to validate the input pram of an SP inside the same sp !*
>
> You need to undergo a validation of input prams.
>   So hear is an simple example to do this with error handling method.

```
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE ERROR_TEST
    (
        @month DATETIME,
        @year  DATETIME
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            MONTH (@month) [month],
            YEAR  (@year)  [year]
    END
GO
```

Now create a similar sp with same input prams.

```
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE ERROR_TEST_1
    (
        @month_1 VARCHAR(50),
        @year_1  VARCHAR(50)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC ERROR_TEST @month_1,@year_1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 8114 --> update asper your error OR set > 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'INVALID MONTH OR YEAR'
        END
    END CATCH;
GO
```

**Sample Execution :**

> **EXEC ERROR_TEST_1 '1','*2*'** ---> Error result
>
> **EXEC ERROR_TEST_1 '*2015-11-15*','*2015-11-15*'**---> correct result