# Stored procedure not getting error log captured into error table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have created below tables and stored procedure and trying to capture log into custom error table in case of both success or failed execution

```
CREATE TABLE  temp (Column1 varchar(50), Column2 int)

CREATE TABLE ErrorTable (
[ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Status]         VARCHAR(10),
[ErrorNumber]    INT           NULL,
[ErrorState]     INT           NULL,
[ErrorSeverity]  INT           NULL,
[ErrorLine]      INT           NULL,
[ErrorProcedure] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[ErrorMessage]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[StartDateTime]  DATETIME      NULL,
[EndDateTime]  DATETIME      NULL,
```

)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertRecord

(
 @Param1 varchar(50),
 @Param2 int
)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
DECLARE @EndTime datetime
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)

SET @StartTime = GETDATE()
SET @TableName ='Temp'

BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM temp;

    -- Insert data into  table
    INSERT INTO temp (Column1, Column2)
    VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)

 SET @EndTime = GETDATE()

 COMMIT  TRANSACTION
    -- Return success message
 SELECT 'Record inserted successfully' AS Message

 -- Insert success message into errortable
    INSERT INTO ErrorTable (Status, ErrorNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLine,ErrorMessage,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
    SELECT 'Success',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,@StartTime,@EndTime  ;

 END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
 ROLLBACK  

    SET @EndTime = GETDATE()

    -- Return custom error message
  SELECT 'Error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS Message

    -- Store error message in error table

INSERT INTO ErrorTable (Status, ErrorNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLine,ErrorMessage,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
 SELECT 'Failed',ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE(),@StartTime,@EndTime ;

  PRINT 'Error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

  END CATCH
END
```

With below query, I am trying to insert valid as well as invalid record to check message in error table

```
EXEC usp_InsertRecord 'Value1', 1234  -- Insert a valid record

EXEC usp_InsertRecord 'Value1', 'Invalid'  -- Attempt to insert an invalid record
```

I am trying to select record from Error table for invalid but I didn't get anything .However, stored procedure throws an error

Here, valid record will insert data into Error table but not failed one . Can someone please guide me where I am doing mistake

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: I am using Azure SQL Server DB

Comment: Is your code entering the catch block? Can you add a dummy `select 'foo'` to see whether your code always enters the catch block when it fails?

Comment: how to debug -execute with debugger is not supported for Azure SQL DB and I tried declaring param1 and param2 and set the invalid record but I still didn't get any dummy  message which I added after catch block

Comment: EXEC usp_InsertRecord 'Value1', 'Invalid' crashes before you even enter procedure because you're using varchar on an INT parameter. If you change parameter type to varchar, it might "work". But then the question becomes, what are you doing inserting varchars into int. Only you can answer that

Comment: So this type of error we can't capture into error log table ? Sorry , I am just learner in writing stored procedure

Comment: So basically, the requirement is to capture the logs in case of error as well as successful execution and In real time , we will not pass any parameter to stored procedure instead it will just insert data into table by selecting records from different table with some transformation so suppose if there is an error while inserting data then it should show in error table

Comment: I have got it basically, in real scenario it will work fine . thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture invalid datatypes being passed as parameters, you have to have parameters defined as VARCHAR datatypes and then handle invalid parameters accordingly. I am using TRY_CAST here to find out invalid parameters and throwing custom errors.

Refer: [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Also refer to [SO Post on similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287662/how-to-handle-procedure-wrong-input-parameters-error-using-exception-block#34291355)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertRecord

(
 @Param1 varchar(50),
 @Param2 varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
DECLARE @EndTime datetime
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)

SET @StartTime = GETDATE()
SET @TableName ='Temp'

BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Throwing custom error in case of invalid parameter
IF TRY_CAST(@param2 AS INT) IS NULL
BEGIN
   THROW 50001, 'Invalid parameter. not an integer', 1
END 

DELETE FROM temp;

    -- Insert data into  table
    INSERT INTO temp (Column1, Column2)
    VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)

 SET @EndTime = GETDATE()

 COMMIT  TRANSACTION
    -- Return success message
 SELECT 'Record inserted successfully' AS Message

 -- Insert success message into errortable
    INSERT INTO ErrorTable (Status, ErrorNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLine,ErrorMessage,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
    SELECT 'Success',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,@StartTime,@EndTime  ;

 END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
 ROLLBACK  

    SET @EndTime = GETDATE()

    -- Return custom error message
  SELECT 'Error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS Message

    -- Store error message in error table

INSERT INTO ErrorTable (Status, ErrorNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLine,ErrorMessage,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
 SELECT 'Failed',ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE(),@StartTime,@EndTime ;

  PRINT 'Error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

  END CATCH
END
```

Comment: `SQL_VARIANT` might be another option. But IMO this whole error-handling is a waste of time, it's best to just catch all errors on the client-side

Comment: @Charlieface, yes. I think we need to have error handling at two levels. first is for the internal logic with TRY CATCH and second is for these kinds wrong parameters and these things for client side catching. First level can be rethrown to the client side.